# Validation accuracy keeps increasing with every epoch (dense neural network in keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to program a simple dense neural network in keras with the breast-cancer-dataset from sklearn.

But when I plot the training and validation accuracy and loss over the Epochs, the validation accuracy keeps improving and the validation loss keeps decreasing, when really it should peak and then diverge from the training values.

graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw1oB.jpg

I've tried playing around with number of layers and other variables, but the problem remains.
I'm thinking that maybe this could be the case if the training and validation data are the same somehow? But I can't find the problem with my code.

Does somebody know how to fix this? Thank you!

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import models, layers#, regularizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = load_breast_cancer()
x = dataset['data']
y = dataset['target_names'].take(dataset['target'])
for index, item in enumerate(y):
    if (item == 'malignant'):
        y[index] = 1.
    else:
        y[index] = 0.
x = scale(x)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.5)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:80]
partial_x_train = x_train[80:]
y_val = y_train[:80]
partial_y_train = y_train[80:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=50,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

history_dict = history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

epochs = range(1, len(history_dict['acc']) + 1)

plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss_values, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.clf()
acc_values = history_dict['acc']
val_acc_values = history_dict['val_acc']

plt.plot(epochs, acc_values, 'bo', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc_values, 'b', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
Train on 204 samples, validate on 80 samples
Epoch 1/20
204/204 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 0.1684 - acc: 0.7941 - val_loss: 0.1735 - val_acc: 0.7750
Epoch 2/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.1387 - acc: 0.8529 - val_loss: 0.1571 - val_acc: 0.8000
Epoch 3/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.1253 - acc: 0.8775 - val_loss: 0.1452 - val_acc: 0.8500
Epoch 4/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.1156 - acc: 0.8775 - val_loss: 0.1354 - val_acc: 0.8625
Epoch 5/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.1074 - acc: 0.8775 - val_loss: 0.1263 - val_acc: 0.8625
Epoch 6/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.1003 - acc: 0.8824 - val_loss: 0.1165 - val_acc: 0.8625
Epoch 7/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0929 - acc: 0.8922 - val_loss: 0.1111 - val_acc: 0.8750
Epoch 8/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0883 - acc: 0.8971 - val_loss: 0.1045 - val_acc: 0.8875
Epoch 9/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0836 - acc: 0.9069 - val_loss: 0.0985 - val_acc: 0.8875
Epoch 10/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0782 - acc: 0.9216 - val_loss: 0.0935 - val_acc: 0.8875
Epoch 11/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0738 - acc: 0.9314 - val_loss: 0.0890 - val_acc: 0.8875
Epoch 12/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0698 - acc: 0.9363 - val_loss: 0.0847 - val_acc: 0.8875
Epoch 13/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0664 - acc: 0.9412 - val_loss: 0.0812 - val_acc: 0.8875
Epoch 14/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 44us/step - loss: 0.0632 - acc: 0.9363 - val_loss: 0.0776 - val_acc: 0.9000
Epoch 15/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 34us/step - loss: 0.0604 - acc: 0.9461 - val_loss: 0.0742 - val_acc: 0.9000
Epoch 16/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0578 - acc: 0.9461 - val_loss: 0.0702 - val_acc: 0.9000
Epoch 17/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0549 - acc: 0.9510 - val_loss: 0.0672 - val_acc: 0.9000
Epoch 18/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0525 - acc: 0.9510 - val_loss: 0.0642 - val_acc: 0.9000
Epoch 19/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0500 - acc: 0.9559 - val_loss: 0.0599 - val_acc: 0.9125
Epoch 20/20
204/204 [==============================] - 0s 39us/step - loss: 0.0471 - acc: 0.9559 - val_loss: 0.0571 - val_acc: 0.9250
```

Comment: You'r model is just still learning. Run you'r model for 100 or 300 epoch and you'll probably see overfiting happen (when validation accuracy start to decrease)

Comment: Btw, if you'r model doesnt overfit after, let's says 500 epoch, then yes you probably have a problem

Comment: @akhetos thanks for your reply! When I run more epochs at some point the validation loss will have a minimum and then very shallowly increase again.. But it doesn't look as clear as the example graph in the book i have at all.. Could that be because the dataset is too small?

Comment: add the learning plot when you run model for more epoch please

Comment: 300 epochs: https://imgur.com/a/uyz1ho4

Comment: 400 epochs: https://imgur.com/a/OgBbqJE

Comment: I made 80% training, 20% test split, and of the training set I took 375 for training, 80 for validation. I used three hidden layers (16 units) and batch size 50.. those seemed to work a little better when I tried out the parameters

Comment: I dont understand why you have a lot of variation in your validation accuracy between epoch, but excepting that, learning curve are normal. Since you have very small  data set, you can try the model with another split; i.e change random split value so you'll get a new validation set. You can also use stratify to get same amount of each class between different set

Comment: + you should have 2 neuron at last layer.. with only one neuron you can only predict 1 class

Comment: Thanks for your help!!